# Override method on parent class

Tags: python, inheritance

Assume we have these two classes:

```
class B(A):
    def process(self):
        for item in self.items:
            self.process_item(item)

class C(B):
    def process(self):
        # Do some other stuff
        super(C, self).process()
```

Now I want to use `C`, but I need `process` to behave something like:

```
def process():
    # Do some other stuff
    for item in self.items:
        try:
            self.process_item(item)
        except ItemError as err:
            handle_error(err)
```

My natural approach would be to subclass `C` as `D` and overwrite `process`.
I do not want to repeat the `#Do some other stuff` part, though. So basically I need to change the behavior of `B.process`. Is there some elegant way to do what I want? I do not own `A`, `B` or `C`.

Comment: Is there a typo here in C.process? It should be `super(C, self)`.

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. Fixed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C is correctly using `super`, you can do some clever things to mess around with the method resolution order and put your own class in between B and C:

```
class Intermediate(B):
    def process(self):
        for item in self.items:
            try:
                self.process_item(item)
            except ItemError as err:
                handle_error(err)

class D(C, Intermediate):
    pass
```

Now, given an instance of D, the super call from C.process will call Intermediate.process rather than B's version.

This does require defining two classes, even if one is empty, so it's a matter of opinion as to whether it's any cleaner than monkey-patching.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the cleanest solution after all. I like how I can now change other parts of `C`s behavior too, without interfering with the parent's implementation too much.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Given the clarification in the comments to this answer, subclassing `C` and using that is definitely the way to go.

**Previously**

You could monkey-patch `A`.

```
def process(self):
    amazing_stuff()

A.process = process
```

Comment: That is my present solution. Would that be what a Python guru would do?

Comment: @karlson that really depends on the specific case. From your question it is implied that you do not own `A` and can't modify it directly, or don't want to. Another possible solution would be to subclass `A` first, wrapping its `process` method, and then subclassing `B` and `C` off of that. If you want to get into "guru" territory, you'd have to examine whether subclassing anything at all is the correct answer here.

Comment: Or you can use a mixin like @daniel-roseman did. Personally I'm very wary of mixins.

Comment: I do not own any of `A`, `B` or `C`, but want to use a version of `C` that does the error handling. I am too not very fond of mixins, but monkey patching doesn't feel 'right' to me either. Hence my question for the generally preferred solution.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the original question, claiming I need to change the behavior of `A.process`, but I actually meant `B.process`. I think your answer needs to change accordingly.

Comment: If all you want is to use `C`, then subclassing it is definitely the way to go. It was not clear from the question that that was your goal. Honestly not sure why you would ever monkeypatch `A` if you use neither it nor `B`.

Comment: Also true, my current solution is monkey-patching `C.process`, but by repeating `some other stuff`. I'd like to be able to be agnostic towards changes of that part in `C`, which is provided by a third party.

Comment: After the update on the answer: So your recommendation would be to repeat whatever `C.process` does on top of `B.process` and then implement the loop over `self.items` without the `super`?

Comment: Why would you do that? You can just use super() or call C.process(self).

Comment: If I do `super(C, self).process()`, where would my error handling come into play?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then your question was extremely unclear. In your process() which part is the equivalent of C.process()? If it's both the other stuff AND process_item(), then yes, you'll need to reimplement a bunch of it. There's no (good) way to inject new code into the middle of an existing function.

Comment: My `process` should do exactly what `C.process` does, with the only difference being, that the loop over `self.items` is handling errors. If the author of `C` decides, that `C.process` should do something more, my class should do the same, without me having to manually copy his/her changes to my subclass. I think @DanielRoseman's mixin-approach might be the way to go in that case after all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97209/discussion-between-roman-levin-and-karlson).